java comparator sort with model array and another field
I have a java class..
public class response_message {

    private String message;
    private String rejectCode;
    private int ruleSeqNo;
    private String contInd;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getRejectCode() {
        return rejectCode;
    }

    public void setRejectCode(String rejectCode) {
        this.rejectCode = rejectCode;
    }

    public int getRuleSeqNo() {
        return ruleSeqNo;
    }

    public void setRuleSeqNo(int ruleSeqNo) {
        this.ruleSeqNo = ruleSeqNo;
    }

    public String getContInd() {
        return contInd;
    }

    public void setContInd(String contInd) {
        this.contInd = contInd;
    }

}

Then an object array of it as well as a string array
private List<response_message> responseMessage = new ArrayList<response_message>();

private String[] reqRejects;

public String[] getReqRejects() {
    return this.reqRejects;
}

public void setReqRejects(String[] reqRejects) {
    this.reqRejects = reqRejects;
}

My requirement is to sort this responseMessage object array with the model string array reqRejects and then with ruleSeqNo (ascending)
Eg.
Input Object array



Message
Reject Code
Rule Seq No
Cont Ind




abcd
60
101
Y


cdef
40
300
Y


xyz
41
280
Y


133
41
270
Y


56f
40
275
Y


677
60
102
Y


hfdd
A5
400
Y



Model String array



Reject Code




A5


40


60


41



The response message object array has reject code column. And reqRejects string array (reject code) is the model array. So, basically, the object array needed to be first sorted on the reject code column in the same order as the reject code model string array is listed. And then on the rule seq no.
Output sorted Object array should be



Message
Reject Code
Rule Seq No
Cont Ind




hfdd
A5
400
Y


56f
40
275
Y


cdef
40
300
Y


abcd
60
101
Y


677
60
102
Y


133
41
270
Y


xyz
41
280
Y



Currently i have done with comparator as below which only sorts on the sequence number
responseMessage.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(m -> m.getRuleSeqNo()));
Thinking how to add the model string array based sort as well to this.

Why is your class name a plural? This makes things confusing

You probably want to use the thenComparing method of the Comparator class.  It's well documented in the Javadoc.

object array has reject code column. and string array reject code is the model array. So, basically, the object array needed to be first sorted on the reject code column in the same order as the reject code model string array is listed. And then on the rule seq no. I believe, i gave clear example.

So what comes first, reject code A5, or 40?

I presume that the recReject array is the order for sorting those codes.  So basically, one just sorts on the index that the given code appears in the array, followed by the ruleSeqNo.

You can do it like this.
List<String> recRejects = List.of("A5", "40", "60", "41");

List<ResponseMessage> list = new ArrayList<>(
        List.of(new ResponseMessage("abcd", "60", 101, "Y"),
                new ResponseMessage("cdef", "40", 300, "Y"),
                new ResponseMessage("xyz", "41", 280, "Y"),
                new ResponseMessage("133", "41", 270, "Y"),
                new ResponseMessage("56f", "40", 275, "Y"),
                new ResponseMessage("677", "60", 102, "Y"),
                new ResponseMessage("hfdd", "A5", 400, "Y")));

list.sort(Comparator
        .<ResponseMessage>comparingInt(msg -> recRejects.indexOf(msg.getRejectCode()))
        .thenComparing(ResponseMessage::getRuleSeqNo));

list.forEach(System.out::println);

Using the the following toString() method added to your class.
 @Override
 public String toString() {
        return "%10s %10s %10s %10s".formatted(message, rejectCode, ruleSeqNo,
                contInd);

Here are the results.
      hfdd         A5        400          Y
       56f         40        275          Y
      cdef         40        300          Y
      abcd         60        101          Y
       677         60        102          Y
       133         41        270          Y
       xyz         41        280          Y


use Comparator.comparingInt to sort on the index of the specified order of the reject codes.
use Comparator.thenComparing for sorting on the next field.


@Grim this result matches the ops result.   You may want to explain your conclusion.

yes reqRejects string array is the order in which the reject codes to be sorted. Per current example, A5 should come first and then 40 then 60 and then 41
